# Was "the Kid" Don's real son?

Tags: character, broken-flowers

It can be said that the movie [*Broken Flowers* (2005)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0412019/) is not about the real father-son situation but even so it makes the viewer curious if the Kid at the end of the movie was Don's real son or not. Are there any sources about the movie which reveal this detail?